# Оповещение после удачного ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, запрос

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после удачного `ajax` запроса выводилось окно, а потом через некоторое время пропадало. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотреть можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/k6zRK/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 1,
    success: function(){
        $('<div id="report">GOOD!</div>').appendTo('body')
            .delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Кроме этого, можно использовать метод [.ajaxSuccess()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)